# Copying Rows from One DataTable to another Displays Nothing

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datatable, ultrawingrid

I'm trying to copy rows from one `DataTable` to another, but only copy rows where the data is yet to be saved to the database table.

The `SQL` side of this is working fine, it's returning the correct number of columns, however, when I add the rows that were found to my second `DataTable` and set it as the `DataSource` for my grid, there is no data displayed, although there is a row that has been added, since the row selector is visible.

What am I doing wrong, and why isn't the data being copied with it?

```
lftable = New DataTable

Try
  For Each dc As DataColumn In lineTable.Columns
    lftable.Columns.Add()
  Next

  Dim ds As New DataSet

  For Each row As DataRow In lineTable.Rows
     Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order_Freight] WHERE [Order_Number] = ? AND [Product_Code] <> ?", con)
     da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@num", OleDbType.Integer).Value = orderNum
     da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prod", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Item("Product_Code")
     da.Fill(ds)

     For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Dim nRow = lftable.Rows.Add()
        nRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray()
     Next
 Next

 ugProducts.DataSource = lfTable
```

Screenshot of the grid after assigning it the `DataSource`

[image]

Comment: @AlexB. Compile error - Expression does not product a value

Comment: Yes my comment was nonsense. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the columns correctly:

```
For Each dc As DataColumn In lineTable.Columns
    lftable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType)); 
Next
```

You can use the overload of the `Row.Add` function which allows you provide the `ItemArray` directly:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
      lftable.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
      'nRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray() <-- remove
Next
```

Comment: which result do you get?

Comment: The same one as in the image

Comment: 1) `ds.Tables(0)` is filled when calling `da.Fill(ds)` and 2) I'm only looping over `ds.Tables(0).Rows` once? Which is inside `lineTable.Rows`

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code  :

```
   ' For Each dc As DataColumn In lineTable.Columns
      '  lftable.Columns.Add()   >
        '  lftable.Columns.Add(dc) 
     ' Next
```

Use DataTable.Clone() to copy only the columns in a lineTable to lftable

```
lftable = lineTable.Clone();
```

And then

```
  For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
         lftable.Rows.Add( dr.ItemArray)
     Next
```

Comment: This gives an error "Column 'Product_ID' already belongs to another DataTable"

Comment: This will not work. @David has to create a new DataColumn object and add this to the collection like `lftable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));`

Comment: @AlexB. "Value of type System.Data.DataColumn cannot be converted to type 'String'"